# RadCarousel control display image count

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, telerik

I'm using RadCarousel control in my WPF MVVM application, where i have to load a set of images for view. The control works fine when i load Minimum of 5 images. If i try loading below the count of 5 the image is not viewed as expected.But after the button is pressed below i can see the images. Also i have to set a default image in those collection of images.

XAML Code:

```
<telerik:RadWindow x:Class="Test.Presentation.View.Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
                   xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Test.Presentation.ViewModel" 
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        Height="600" Width="600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <telerik:RadWindow.Resources>
        <ViewModel:MarketSeriesViewModel x:Key="ViewModel1"/>

    </telerik:RadWindow.Resources>
    <Grid DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel1}">

        <GroupBox>
            <Grid >
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Path x:Key="path"
                  Data="M30,347 L307.5,347"
                  Stroke="#FF0998f8"
                  StrokeThickness="2"
                  Stretch="Fill" />
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:CarouselItem}">
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type telerik:CarouselItem}">
                                    <Grid x:Name="grid"
                                  Height="190"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                  Width="250">
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                                        CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="#cecece">

                                            <Border BorderThickness="0"
                                            CornerRadius="0"
                                            Margin="0">
                                                <Border.BorderBrush>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                                 StartPoint="0.5,0">

                                                        <GradientStop Color="White"
                                                              Offset="0.13" />

                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.BorderBrush>
                                                <Border.Background>
                                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                                 StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                        <GradientStop Color="White"
                                                              Offset="0.26" />

                                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                </Border.Background>
                                                <Grid>
                                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <RowDefinition Height="24" />
                                                        <RowDefinition />

                                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <Border Grid.Row="0"
                                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                                    Margin="0"
                                                    VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                                    Height="24"
                                                    CornerRadius="2,2,0,0">
                                                        <Border.Background>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                                                         StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#21a2de"
                                                                      Offset="1" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#21a2de"
                                                                      Offset="0.1" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#21a2de"
                                                                      Offset="0.57" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="#21a2de"
                                                                      Offset="0.11" />
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Border.Background>
                                                        <Border.BorderBrush>
                                                            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5"
                                                                         StartPoint="0,0.5">
                                                                <GradientStop Offset="0" />
                                                                <GradientStop Offset="1" />
                                                                <GradientStop Color="White"
                                                                      Offset="0.5" />
                                                            </LinearGradientBrush>
                                                        </Border.BorderBrush>
                                                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel"
                                                            Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                            Margin="6,0,0,0">
                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RDNumber}"
                                                               TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                                               Foreground="White"
                                                               FontSize="11"
                                                               TextAlignment="Center"/>
                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1"
                                                        Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                        <Image VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                       Source="{Binding ImagePath}"
                                                       Stretch="Fill" 
                                                       Height="160" Width="250" />
                                                    </StackPanel>

                                                </Grid>
                                            </Border>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>

                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>                  

                <TextBox x:Name="txtInput" Grid.Row="0" Width="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <telerik:RadButton Grid.Row="0" Width="100" Content="Load" Margin="100,0,0,0" Click="RadButton_Click"/>
                    <telerik:RadCarousel x:Name="radCarousel1" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding ImageCollectionById, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                         Background="Transparent" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" 
                                                        VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="False" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" Focusable="True">

                    <telerik:RadCarousel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditImage}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="MetaData"/>
                            <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteImage}"/>
                        </ContextMenu>

                    </telerik:RadCarousel.ContextMenu>
                    <telerik:RadCarousel.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <telerik:RadCarouselPanel Path="{StaticResource path}" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8" AutoLoadItems="True" IsSelectedTopItem="True">

                            </telerik:RadCarouselPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </telerik:RadCarousel.ItemsPanel>
                </telerik:RadCarousel>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </GroupBox>
    </Grid>
</telerik:RadWindow>
```

Xmal.cs Code:

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Telerik.Windows.Controls;
    using Telerik.Windows.Controls.Navigation;

    namespace Test.Presentation.View
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for Window1.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class Window1 : RadWindow
        {
            public Window1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                RadWindowInteropHelper.SetShowInTaskbar(this, true);

                m_cImageCollection = new ObservableCollection<ImageClass>();
                m_cImageCollectionbyId = new ObservableCollection<ImageClass>();
                LoadImageCollection();

            }

            private ObservableCollection<ImageClass> m_cImageCollection;
            private ObservableCollection<ImageClass> m_cImageCollectionbyId;

            public ObservableCollection<ImageClass> ImageCollection
            {
                get { return this.m_cImageCollection; }
                set
                {
                    if (this.m_cImageCollection != value)
                    {
                        this.m_cImageCollection = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            public ObservableCollection<ImageClass> ImageCollectionById
            {
                get { return this.m_cImageCollectionbyId; }
                set
                {
                    if (this.m_cImageCollectionbyId != value)
                    {
                        this.m_cImageCollectionbyId = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            private void LoadImageCollection()
            {
                try
                {
                    ImageClass NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 1;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Chair.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = true;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 1;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Cot1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 1;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\DiningSet1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 1;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Havana restaurant chair.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 1;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Sofa1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 1;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Sofa2.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 2;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Sofa3.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 2;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\StudyRoomSet.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 2;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\TVStand1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 3;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Wadroop1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 4;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Wall1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 4;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Sofa1.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);


                    NewImage = new ImageClass();
                    NewImage.Id = 5;
                    NewImage.ImagePath = @"U:\My Documents\Projects\Images\Sofa3.jpeg";
                    NewImage.IsDefault = false;
                    ImageCollection.Add(NewImage);

                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                    throw;
                }
            }

            private void RadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                var ss = txtInput.Text;

                ImageCollectionById = new ObservableCollection<ImageClass>( ImageCollection.Where(x => x.Id == Convert.ToInt32(ss)).ToList());

                radCarousel1.ItemsSource = ImageCollectionById;

            }
        }

        public class ImageClass
        {
            private Int32 m_iId;
            private string m_sImagePath;
            private bool m_bIsDefault;

            public Int32 Id
            {
                get { return this.m_iId; }
                set
                {
                    if (this.m_iId != value)
                    {
                        this.m_iId = value;
                    }
                }
            }

            public string ImagePath
            {
                get { return this.m_sImagePath; }
                set
                {
                    if (this.m_sImagePath != value)
                    {
                        this.m_sImagePath = value;
                    }
                }

            }

            public bool IsDefault
            {
                get { return this.m_bIsDefault; }
                set
                {
                    if (this.m_bIsDefault != value)
                    {
                        this.m_bIsDefault = value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**FYI:**

Below code its work fine as i expected. This code is used in `xmal.cs` file. But i need this functionality in MVVM pattern without attach behaviour.

```
radcarousel1.BringDataIntoView(Item)
```